Issues with Cookies Not Appearing in Browser for GraphQL Requests Across Microservices
Issue with Cookies in Local Development
Hi everyone,
I have two microservices: Auth (using GraphQL Yoga) and Gateway (using GraphQL Mesh). The services are deployed locally on ports 3000 and 4000 respectively. When I navigate to http://localhost:3000/graphql and perform a mutation request, cookies appear in the browser as expected. However, when I perform the same request at http://localhost:4000/graphql, no cookies appear in the browser.
Here are the relevant configurations:
.meshrc.yaml:
sources:
  - name: Auth
    handler:
      graphql:
        endpoint: http://localhost:3000/graphql
plugins:
  - httpDetailsExtensions:
      if: "env.NODE_ENV === 'development'"
pollingInterval: 3600000
serve:
  playground: true
  hostname: 0.0.0.0
  cors:
    credentials: true
    origin: http://localhost:4000

session.ts:
export function setCookie(ctx: GraphQLContext, name: TokenType, token: string, expires: string | number) {
  ctx.request.cookieStore?.set({
    name,
    sameSite: COOKIES_SAME_SITE as CookieSameSite,
    secure: en(COOKIES_SECURE),
    domain: COOKIES_DOMAIN!,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + ms(expires.toString())),
    value: token,
    httpOnly: en(COOKIES_HTTPONLY)
  });
}

export function assignAuthorizationCookies(ctx: GraphQLContext, { id, name, email, phone }: { id: string, name: string, email?: string | null, phone?: string | null }) {
  const accessToken = generateToken({ id, name, email, phone }, JWT_TOKEN!, SESSION_EXPIRES!);
  setCookie(ctx, TokenType.ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken, SESSION_EXPIRES!);
  const refreshToken = generateToken({ id }, REFRESH_TOKEN!, REFRESH_SESSION_EXPIRES!);
  setCookie(ctx, TokenType.REFRESH_TOKEN, refreshToken, REFRESH_SESSION_EXPIRES!);
}

Mutation and Response Details
Mutation:
mutation {
  loginUser(emailOrPhone: "88005553535", password: "password") {
    name
  }
}

Response:
{
  "data": {
    "loginUser": {
      "name": "Name"
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "httpDetails": [
      {
        "sourceName": "Auth",
        "request": {
          "timestamp": 1722756057656,
          "url": "http://localhost:3000/graphql",
          "method": "POST",
          "headers": {
            "accept": "application/graphql-response+json, application/json, multipart/mixed",
            "content-type": "application/json"
          }
        },
        "response": {
          "timestamp": 1722756060429,
          "status": 200,
          "statusText": "OK",
          "headers": {
            "set-cookie": [
              "accessToken=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjY2YTMzODFlNDc3YjQwZWI2YzY5MGYwZCIsIm5hbWUiOiJUaW11ciIsImVtYWlsIjpudWxsLCJwaG9uZSI6Iis3OTg3MDU5OTEzNyIsImlhdCI6MTcyM; Domain=localhost; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 04 Aug 2024 21:21:21 GMT; SameSite=Strict; HttpOnly",
              "refreshToken=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjY2YTMzODFlNDc3YjQwZWI2YzY5MGYwZCIsImlhdCI; Domain=localhost; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 03 Sep 2024 21:21:21 GMT; SameSite=Strict; HttpOnly"
            ],
            "content-type": "application/graphql-response+json; charset=utf-8",
            "date": "Sun, 04 Aug 2024 07:21:00 GMT",
            "content-length": "39"
          }
        },
        "responseTime": 2773
      }
    ]
  }
}

Any ideas on why cookies are not being set for requests to the Gateway service? Thank you!
CORS Configuration
I also tried configuring CORS, but it didn't help:
app.ts (Auth):
export const yoga = createYoga({
  ...
  plugins: [
    ...
    useCookies(),
    ...
  ],
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: ['X-Custom-Header'],
    methods: ['POST']
  }
});

.meshrc.yaml (Gateway):
cors:
  credentials: true
  origin: http://localhost:4000

